# XMLHttpRequest cannot load firebase cloud function url even after using cors

Tags: ajax, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write on my firebase real time database through https triggered function with Admin SDK, When a button (id=change) is clicked.

This is is the ajax get method in client side code

```
  $('#change').click(function(){
              $.ajax({
           url: 'https://<CLOUD FUNCTION URL>/verifyuser?uid='+user.uid,
           type: "GET",
           cache: false,
           dataType: "text",
           crossDomain: true,
           success : function(result){console.log(result);},
           error : function(error){console.log(error);}
    });
       });
```

Given below is my firebase cloud function which triggers on http request.

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin=require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
 const cors=require('cors')({origin: true});
 exports.verifyuser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => { 
  const uid=req.query.uid;

admin.database.ref('/tathva17/users/'+uid+'/hospitality').set(
{'status':'confirmed'}).then(function(){
   res.status(200).send("Success!"); 
});

});
});
```

Error shown in my console after clicking button (id="change")

[image]

error seen in Logs
[image]

Comment: What was logged in the functions console?

Comment: *“The response had HTTP status code 500”* indicates the real problem is some internal server failure that’s unrelated to the CORS config. The only reason you end up seeing that CORS error message in the browser is: many servers typically don’t send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in 500 responses or other error responses—instead they only send Access-Control-Allow-Origin for ok-status/success responses. So it’s not a CORS problem & instead what you probably want to do is: check your server logs on the server side to see what message is logged there about the cause of that 500 internal failure.

Comment: it gives a type error saying admin.database.ref() is not a function.I don't get how it's not a function

Comment: use like this `admin.database().ref()` @AdeebAbdulSalam

Answer (score 2):

Try using ajax like this, as a cross domain access, you need to set dataType as `jsonp`

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'https://<CLOUD FUNCTION URL>/verifyuser?uid='+user.uid,
       type: "GET",
       cache: false,
       dataType: "jsonp",
       success : function(result){console.log(result);},
       error : function(error){console.log(error);}
});
```